# prevent jumping back to top of screen jQuery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, gsap

I have two 'screens' with different background images.

when the user clicks on the down arrow it scrolls from one 'screen' to the one below. The second screen is set to display none at the beginning. This all works as expected, however, when trying to scroll to the top of the screen again it jumps to the top as opposed to smoothly scrolling back to the top. I am also using [GSAPs tween library](http://greensock.com/gsap) for other animations.

Please see code below:

**JS**

```
 $('.down-arrow').click(function() {
    var tl = new TimelineMax();
    tl.set('.background-two', {display: 'block', onComplete: scrollDown})
    tl.set('.background-one', {display: 'none', delay: 0.6})

    function scrollDown(){
          $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(window).height()}, 600);
    }

  });


  $('.up-arrow').click(function() {
    var tl = new TimelineMax();
    tl.set('.background-one', {display: 'block', onComplete: scrollUp})
    tl.set('.background-two', {display: 'none', delay: 0.6})
    function scrollUp(){
          $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600);
    }
  });
```

**CSS**

```
.background-one {
    background: url(../img/Background1.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.background-two {
    background: url(../img/Background2.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="background-one">
   <div class="up-arrow">UP</div>
</div>
<div class="background-two">
   <div class="down-arrow">DOWN</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when you set the top block to `display: block;` it appears immediately and pushes down your bottom block.

What you could try instead is sliding the blocks in (By animating their heights instead of scrolling).

Comment: i think you may be right. How would you go about doing this?

Comment: If they are a fixed height you can animate their heights with TweenLite using something like TweenLite.to($element, 1, {css:{height: '0px'}});

If they are variable height it's a bit more difficult, but you can do it using max-height instead

Answer (score -1):

Does it work when you properly close your html div-tags?

Edit:

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h55161d8/), the animation works fine. You're removing (display:none) the other element, which causes the page to flicker/jump.

```
function scrollDown(){
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(window).height()}, 600);
}
function scrollUp(){
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600);
}
$('.down-arrow').click(function() {
  var tl = new TimelineMax();
  tl.set('.background-two', {display: 'block', onComplete: scrollDown})
  tl.set('.background-one', {display: 'none', delay: 0.6})
  });


  $('.up-arrow').click(function() {
    var tl = new TimelineMax();
    tl.set('.background-one', {display: 'block', onComplete: scrollUp})
    tl.set('.background-two', {display: 'none', delay: 0.6})

  });
```

Tip: Keep your functions outside your click-handler.

Comment: that doesn't work, it is the same issue. your animation doesn't work on jsfiddle either